# PowerShell Script for checking contents of log file in network share

Tags: powershell, networking, share, logfile

I'm trying to write a PS script to check a network folder which contains logfiles of erased systems, when the erase is run the output contains the system serial number, as part of the logfile name, so instead of scrolling or searching the network share manually I need a script that will check the network share for a series of serial numbers which I have in a CSV.

Currently I was trying this but it's failing:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$sourceFolder = '\\domain\share\share\'
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\Serials.csv'
foreach ($item in $data) {

    $search = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter $item.Serial -File -Recurse -ErrorAction          SilentlyContinue | 
              Select-Object -First 1

    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Present -Value (@($search).Count -gt 0)
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I've tried the script listed above and was hoping for the listed serials to show up with true beside them if they existed.

Comment: There's no obvious problem with your code. What, specifically, doesn't work as you expect? Does the exported data look OK except it is missing a `Present` column?

Comment: it never outputs, ive ran it a number of times, with 2 serials listed and 30 serials listed and it never writes back to the output folder, i thought i had it working when id left out the 'Serial' field in the csv, and it threw back the output with 'TRUE' beside every serial in a matter of seconds, but when i add the Serial header back in it just sits there and does nothing. i tried adding a progress bar to the script but i honestly dont know what im doing when it comes to this, im new to it all. perhaps i just have to be patient...lol

Comment: @PConroy Add `-PassThru` to the `Add-Member` command if you want the (modified) item rendered as output

Answer (score 3):

Given that there's no conceptual problem with your code, based on your comment your issue may just be needing to be patient waiting for processing to *finish*:

- Each `Get-ChildItem -Filter ... -Recurse ...` call inside your `foreach` loop can potentially take a long time to finish, if the target directory tree is large, especially on a *network* drive.
- Since you're modifying *all* objects in your `$data` array *up front*, it can take a long time before the `Export-Csv` call is reached and file output is produced.

The following, PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of your code uses a *single pipeline* with *streaming* output to the target CSV file, causing the output file to be filled one row at a time. For visual feedback, a simple `Write-Host` command is used to signal whenever a new output object gets emitted, by printing a single `.`:

```bash
$sourceFolder = '\\domain\share\share\'
Import-Csv C:\folder\Serials.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    $present = [bool] (
      Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter $_.Serial -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
      Select-Object -First 1
    )
    # Add the `.Present` property and output the modified object,
    # thanks to `-PassThru`
    $_ | Add-Member -PassThru Present $present
    # Simple, less performance-interfering substitute for a progress display:
    # Print a "." for every object emitted.
    Write-Host -NoNewline .
  } |
  Export-Csv C:\folder\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Thus, even if the *total* runtime is large, you should see "wandering dots" in your terminal indicating progress, with each dot representing a new object being emitted / exported.